# PNG Satellite image on map

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy, satellite

i know it is simple if I had the coordinates... know i only have a Image of a sat-bild and want to cut a region.
The Image is available on: http://www.fennec.imperial.ac.uk/

There is a option to look on the coordinates by a click on (high-resolution), but I don't trust my click skills.

So is there a option to plot this image on a bigger cartopy or basemap map to find the corrdination and extract the corners to calculate the other points using the pixels?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image appears to be in the (original) geostationary projection. You can guess the corner coordinates for that projection, and overlay it (in QGIS for example) and iteratively refine your guess.

For example:

```
gdal_translate -a_sr`s "+proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785831 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -a_ullr -3170000 4180000 2828000 285000 -of VRT 201804020515_dst.jpg 201804020515_dst.vrt`
```

That's already is a decent approximation. Once georeferenced you can use any GIS software you like to create a crop.

[image]